# Unity - How to calculate new position for an object from pitch of another object in 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to calculate a new position based on the pitch of a mesh in order to make an object following the top of my object which is rotated:

[image: first_img]

And result in:

[image: second_img]

**I cannot make the square object as represented above as a child (in the Unity object hierarchy) of the line object because the rotated object can see its scale changed at anytime.**

Does a mathematics solution can be used in this case?

Comment: Depending on what the objects actually are, you could parent them both to a common gameobject which defines the pitch by rotating it, then the "rotated object" can be scaled separately using its own transform. The question is a bit too abstract to say for sure if this would work for you though.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I cannot modify the Unity object hierarchy in my case

Comment: Ok, is it in 2D or 3D?

Comment: is in 3D sorry I have updated the title

Comment: How generic are the shapes - is it a cube and a plane? Or could be be e.g. a sphere that needs to "stick" to the surface of any shaped object?

Comment: The reals object are : a pole for the "line" in my example above, and a for the "rectangle" it's an object used to transport electricity called "Cross Arms for Pin Insulator" @LukeBriggs

Comment: Can you edit the pole gameobject? (I guess it's a prefab?)

Comment: @LukeBriggs the pole is effectively a prefab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hotspots

If you'd like to place something at a particular location on a generic object which can be scaled or transformed anywhere, then a "hotspot" can be particularly useful.

## What's a hotspot?

Edit the target gameobject (the line in this case) and add an empty gameobject to it. Give it some appropriate name - "cross arms hotspot" for example, and then move it to the location where you'd like your other gameobject to target. Essentially, a hotspot is just an empty gameobject - a placement marker of sorts.

## How do I use it?

All you need is a reference to the hotspot gameobject. You could do this by adding a little script to the pole gameobject which tracks it for you:

```cs
public class PowerPole : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject CrossArmsHotspot; // Set this in the inspector
}
```

Then you can get that hotspot reference from any power pole instance like this:

```cs
var targetHotspot = aPowerPoleGameObject.GetComponent<PowerPole>().CrossArmsHotspot;
```

Then it's just a case of getting your target object to place itself where that hotspot is, using whichever technique you prefer. If you want it to just "stick" there, then:

```cs
void Start(){
   targetHotspot = aPowerPoleGameObject.GetComponent<PowerPole>().CrossArmsHotspot;
}

void Update(){
    transform.position = targetHotspot.transform.position;
}
```

would be a (simplfied) example.

A more advanced example using lerp to move towards the hotspot:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CrossArmsMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PowerPole;
    private GameObject targetHotspot;
    public GameObject CrossArms;
    public float TimeToTake = 5f;
    private float timeSoFar;
    private Vector3 startPosition;
    private Quaternion startRotation;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startPosition = CrossArms.transform.position;
        startRotation = CrossArms.transform.rotation;
        targetHotspot = PowerPole.GetComponent<PowerPole>().CrossArmsHotspot;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        timeSoFar+=Time.deltaTime;

        var progress = timeSoFar/TimeToTake;

        // Clamp it so it doesn't go above 1.
        if(progress > 1f){
            progress = 1f;
        }

        // Target position / rotation is..
        var targetPosition = targetHotspot.transform.position;
        var targetRotation = targetHotspot.transform.rotation;

        // Lerp towards that target transform:
        CrossArms.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, targetPosition, progress);
        CrossArms.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startRotation, targetRotation, progress);

    }
}
```

[image: Using Lerp whilst moving the target object around]

Comment: I think it's the easier solution by having a sticky behavior on an object.

Comment: @loic.lopez I've added in a visual and also the code which made that happen :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put a script on the following gameobject in wich you would put :

```
GameObject pitcher = //reference to the gameobject with the pitch;

const int DISTANCE_ON_LINE = //distance between the 2 objects

void Update() {
    transform.position = pitcher.transform.position + pitcher.transform.forward * DISTANCE_ON_LINE;
}
```